# Как пишутся названия сюжетных арок?

Tags: ономастика, кавычки

Скажите, верно ли, что названия сюжетных арок нужно заключать в кавычки? Например, в аниме-сериале "Сейлор Мун" есть арки "Тёмное королевство", "Чёрная Луна", "Мечта" и пр.

Кстати, порой встречаются варианты перевода в родительном падеже. Тогда кавычки, думается, не нужны, ведь в этих случаях логика такая: арка кого/чего, да? Арка Тёмного королевства, арка Чёрной Луны (это название клана), арка мечты?..